# How to use jsonb_populate_record() to insert into a table containing an IDENTITY column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, jsonb, postgres15

I demonstrate the issue with the following simple table. (The actual table and JSON document have a lot more fields.)

```
CREATE table contact (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    firstname VARCHAR,
    lastname VARCHAR,
    birthday timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

I am trying to insert into this table from a JSONB using `jsonb_populate_record`:

```
INSERT INTO contact (firstname, lastname, birthday)
SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(NULL::contact, 
'{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "birthday": "2023-09-28"
}'
)).*;
```

This fails with error:

> ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
> LINE 1: ...O contact (firstname, lastname, birthday) SELECT
> jsonb_popu...

I understand that the error is coming from the JSONB not containing the `id` key and value. So, the `jsonb_populate_record` function is creating a record with the `id` column but since it's not specified in the `INSERT`, it fails.

I have tried adding `id` into the `INSERT INTO contact (id, ....` but that fails with error that the `id` is null (because my JSONB doesn't have any `id` in it).

How can I make it work so that the `id` is `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` as specified in the table?

**EDIT:**

I was able to find a solution:

```
INSERT INTO contact (id, firstname, lastname, birthday)
SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(NULL::contact, jsonb_set('{
"firstname": "John",
"lastname": "Doe",
"birthday": "2023-09-28"
}', '{id}', to_jsonb(nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('contact', 'id')))))).*;
```

However, the `id` generated after this seems to be skipping 4 digits:

```
select * from contact;
 id | firstname | lastname |        birthday        
----+-----------+----------+------------------------
 10 | John      | Doe      | 2023-09-28 00:00:00-04
 14 | John      | Doe      | 2023-09-28 00:00:00-04
 18 | John      | Doe      | 2023-09-28 00:00:00-04
 22 | John      | Doe      | 2023-09-28 00:00:00-04
```

Any idea why and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another solution, one that doesn't touch the sequence by itself. Just create a custom data type, without the id and use this type:

```
CREATE TYPE CONTACT_BASE AS
(
    firstname VARCHAR,
    lastname  VARCHAR,
    birthday  TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO contact (firstname, lastname, birthday)
SELECT (JSONB_POPULATE_RECORD(
        NULL::CONTACT_BASE -- this one
    , '{
          "firstname": "John",
          "lastname": "Doe",
          "birthday": "2023-09-28"
        }'
    )).*;
```

By the way, why do use a timestamp for the date of birth?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. This is just dummy data. I am not actually using date of birth. In real data, timestamp is being used for when content is posted by a user. Birthday just came to my mind when I was testing the dummy data for this post.

Answer (score 1):

Decomposing the record returned from a function immediately results in a query plan where the function is evaluated once for every column. (`SELECT (func()).*`) The effect gets much worse for your actual JSON document with many columns. This shortcoming of the Postgres query planer wastes performance and can have unfortunate side effects like you observed: it fetches the next serial number from the sequence with every function call.

To avoid that, call the function **once** in a subquery instead and only decompose on the next query level like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO contact (id, firstname, lastname, birthday)
SELECT *
FROM   jsonb_populate_record(NULL::contact
                           , jsonb_set('{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "birthday": "2023-09-28"}', '{id}'
                                     , to_jsonb(nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('contact', 'id')))
                                      )
                            );
```

Related:

- [Avoid multiple calls on same function when expanding composite result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391293/avoid-multiple-calls-on-same-function-when-expanding-composite-result/24399074#24399074)
- [Select from PostgreSQL function that returns composite type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284762/select-from-postgresql-function-that-returns-composite-type/8108475#8108475)

Note: this addresses the particular issue you asked for. **Omitting** the `id` column from the `INSERT`, so it's filled with its default value  is a more efficient solution - if you are at liberty to register a row type for the purpose. See [Frank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77198716/939860).

Actually, you should do **both**. Evaluating the function multiple times would still be a pointless waste, even when avoiding the visible side effects.